# Which view do I use to pick an email address or phone number on iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I have found ABPeoplePickerNavigationViewController.

Is there something similar to pick a specific email address of phone number?

I found this tutorial: http://www.alexyork.net/blog/post/Selecting-a-contact-from-the-Address-Book-with-MonoTouch.aspx

This dismisses the "people picker" when I click on the contact.

However, if I drop this, I can click on an email address or phone number, but I can't see an event to handle in order to pick up on that (no pun intended.)

So is there something that does this? Or do I have to first pick the contact, extract the information required, and build my own UI to pick the relevant information?

Note that I use MonoTouch (aka Mono/.NET), but any Objective-C solution is good enough.

Answer (score 1):

> This dismisses the "people picker" when I click on the contact.

You can customize `ABPeoplePickerNavigationViewController` by providing your own [`ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) implementation.

Your own implementation should override the `ShouldContinue` overloads and deciding when the picker should be closed (or continue it's execution).

> build my own UI to pick the relevant information?

You can create your own pickers but that's quite a bit more work. You better try customizing the existing one first.